# How to check if all elements of an array exists in a table?

Tags: mysql, database, exists

Lets take an array of ids of size n in the application. for instance [132,3425,13,13,... 392] where n is bigger than 100k entries. Some of this entries are repeated.

I need to check if all of these registers are contained in a MySQL table containing more than 5M entries.

Now I'm checking one after another, but this process takes a very long time.
How can I make this verification in one single check, or maybe make this more efficient.

I would like to know if all of them exists on the table, and, if possible, know which don't already exists on that table.

Comment: `"array of ids"` Where is the array stored (application level or in some table)?

Comment: May be you can use `in` clause. Example `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE ids IN (arr)`

Comment: You insert those ids in a (temporary) table, remove duplicates, then join with 5M table.